# Upgrading qt version on ubuntu to use QopenGLWidget

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I need to use QOpenglWidget and it is available for qt 5.4 and higher. When I run qmake --version it shows that I am using version 5.2.1. I tired download qt 5.7 but nothing changes. How can I upgrade the version of the qt on this machine to 5.4 or higher ?

Comment: *but nothing changes* hu? How did you install the new version of Qt?

Comment: with the online installer provided in qt website

Comment: since the online installer is not part of the OS package managed files you'll probably find the libraries and executables under `/usr/opt` or `/opt/` some other directory that doesn't overwrite your default files. See [this Ubuntu SO question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435564/qt5-installation-and-path-configuration)

Comment: @PeterT I am brand new to linux. Does this mean I have to change the directory? with qtdir ?

Comment: You just need to run `qmake`, `qtcreator` etc. coming from that package. Assuming you installed the package from the website in `/foo/bar/`, then run `/foo/bar/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator` (or similar).

Comment: By the way which version of Ubuntu you are using? Latest LTS version 16.04, comes with Qt 5.5. If its not too late I suggest you to switch to a newer distribution.

Answer (score 0):

My version of ubuntu is 14.04 and I don't have the permission to upgrade it. What I did was to change all the subdirectories with cmake-gui to find the proper cmake(QT5_DIR, ...) files in Qt5.7.0. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about this but: cmake uses `qmake` executable to find the Qt directories. Instead of setting Qt directories individually, you can alter the $PATH environment variable so that when you run cmake, it uses the qmake version you want and it will set the Qt directories correctly.

Comment: @HeyYO: Thanks for the advice. As i mentioned I am brand new to Linux and I don't know how to do it.